# creating a varying electric field across a copper strip

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electromagnetic-radiation, electricity, electric-circuits

Hi I am trying to create a varying electric field (by position on copper strip) across a copper strip by attempting a standing wave pattern. the following is a diagram

[image]

may I have some guidance on how i can create such a structure? I want to use this to remotely turn on devices without contact.

Comment: A [Lecher line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lecher_line) might help?